# SED: addressing two lines before match

Tags: regex, unix, sed

Print line, which is situated 2 lines before the match(pattern).

I tried next:

```
sed -n ': loop
/.*/h
:x
{n;n;/cen/p;}
s/./c/p
t x
s/n/c/p
t loop
{g;p;}
' datafile
```

Comment: a good question with beautiful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;$!{N;s/\n/&/2;Ta};/^PATTERN\'\''/MP;$!D' file
```

This will print the line 2 lines before the `PATTERN` throughout the file.

Comment: -1. A one-line file should always give nothing. But if the line is `PATTERN`, this script will print it.

Answer (score 5):

The script:

```
  sed -n "1N;2N;/XXX[^\n]*$/P;N;D"
```

works as follows:

- Read the first *three* lines into the pattern space, `1N;2N`
- Search for the test string `XXX` anywhere in the last line, and if found print the first line of the pattern space, `P`
- Append the next line input to pattern space, `N`
- Delete first line from pattern space and restart cycle without any new read, `D`, noting that `1N;2N` is no longer applicable

Answer (score 3):

This one with grep, a bit simpler solution and easy to read [However need to use one pipe]:
`grep -B2 'pattern' file_name | sed -n '1,2p'`

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `awk` try this:

```
awk  '/pattern/ {print b} {b=a;a=$0}' file
```

This will print two line before `pattern`

Comment: This only print the seccond line before the match, if you need the seccond and the first line before the match try ``awk  '/^commit .*/ {print b"\n"a} {b=a;a=$0}' file``

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command but the result is strange (and obviously wrong), and you didn't give any explanation. You will have to save three lines in a buffer (named *hold space*), do a pattern search with the newest line and print the oldest one if it matches:

```
sed -n '
    ## At the beginning read three lines.
    1 { N; N }
    ## Append them to "hold space". In following iterations it will append
    ## only one line.
    H 
    ## Get content of "hold space" to "pattern space" and check if the 
    ## pattern matches. If so, extract content of first line (until a 
    ## newline) and exit.
    g
    /^.*\nsix$/ { 
        s/^\n//
        P
        q 
    }
    ## Remove the old of the three lines saved and append the new one.
    s/^\n[^\n]*//
    h
' infile
```

Assuming and input file (`infile`) with following content:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

It will search `six` and as output will yield:

```
four
```

Comment: -1 This will only handle the _first_ matching pattern in the file (although admittedly the OP's question is unclear).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other variants:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} /pattern/ {f=NR} END {print a[f-2]}' file
```

This stores all lines in an array `a`.  When pattern is found store line number.
At then end print that line number from the file.
PS may be slow with large files

---

Here is another one:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /pattern/ {f=NR;next} f-2==FNR' file{,}
```

This reads the file twice (`file{,}` is the same as `file file`)
At first round it finds the pattern and store line number in variable `f`
Then at second round it prints the line two before the value in `f`