# Sed: print 2 lines before a match

Tags: sed

I need to print the two previous lines before matches inside a file (for any match)
How to make it?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need `sed`? It could be done with `awk` or even better `grep -B`

Answer (score 5):

The script:

```
  sed -n "1N;2N;/XXX[^\n]*$/{h;s/\n[^\n]*$//;p;g};N;D"
```

works as follows:

- Read the first *three* lines into the pattern space, `1N;2N`
- Search for the test string `XXX` in the last line, and if found: save pattern space in hold space `h`, delete last line `s`, print `p`, and then restore saved string `g`
- Append the next line input to pattern space, `N`
- Delete first line from pattern space and restart cycle, `D`, noting that `1N;2N` is no longer applicable

See also similar [SED: addressing two lines before match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20818643/318716).

Comment: this script did not for "file1": AAA \n BBB \n CCC \n XXX  with pattern "XXX"

Comment: @alwaystudent: Thank you for your comment. I have double-checked my solution with GNU `sed`, and it works OK. What version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: @ Joseph Quinsey :   GNU sed version 4.2.1

Answer (score 4):

If you do not insist on using sed, use

```
grep -B 2
```

Comment: OK, but how to make it on sed?

Comment: Why do you need to, if grep does it in a much simpler way? Always good to question why you need to use a specific tool, rather than accomplish a specific task.