# get N lines above from the section obtained using sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep

need your help , I am stuck at some syntax error after applying sed,
i need to pick 2-3 lines above including the section which i got after applying sed.

PLease help , Thanks in advance.
here is my data

```
Line 1
Line 2
line 3
Line 4
Section_A
blah1
blah2
blah3
blah4
Section_B
Line 11
Line 12
line 13
Line 14
```

Output

```
line 3
Line 4
Section_A
blah1
blah2
blah3
blah4
Section_B
```

this is what i have tried so far.

```
sed  -e '/Section_A/,/Section_B/p' test.txt
sed  -e '/Section_A/1/,/Section_B/p' test.txt
```

Comment: Do you _have to_ use sed?

Comment: What if `Section_B` isn't present in the input but `Section_A` is or vice-versa? What if they're overlapping? What if they're nested? What if they contain regexp metachars? What if they match substrings in other text? etc., etc.

Comment: what is best feasible solution in quickest and simplest way.. i have my data already segregtaed using regex. there will be only one section A and one section B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
tag1="Section_A"
tag2="Section_B"
sed -n "/$tag1/,/$tag2/{p;d}; 1N;2N;/$tag1[^\n]*$/{h;s/\n[^\n]*$//;p;g};N;D" test.txt
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20893302/3776858

Comment: i did tried this one. but was not able to understand the arguments used. if possible can you help me to understand the arguments used.

Comment: @Prayag: Okay, I've updated my answer. I hope this helps you.

Comment: @Prayag: Yes, I've fixed this typo now.

Comment: Perhaps `sed -En 'H;x;s/.*\n(([^\n]*\n){2}(Section_)A.*\3B.*)$/\1/p;x' file` ?

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '
/^Section_A$/ {s = pp ORS p}
s != "" {s = s ORS $0}
/^Section_B$/ {print s; s=""}
{pp=p; p=$0}' file

line 3
Line 4
Section_A
blah1
blah2
blah3
blah4
Section_B
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^Section_A$/{print pp; print p; f=1} f; 
       /^Section_B$/{f=0} {pp=p; p=$0}' file

line 3
Line 4
Section_A
blah1
blah2
blah3
blah4
Section_B
```

Comment: Hmm I took similar approach but only difference is that it will print till end of file if `Section_B` is missing.

Comment: Right, unspecified so any outcome is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes find it conceptually easier to reverse the file. Then you're looking for 3 lines *after* "Section_A"

```sh
tac file \
| awk '
    /Section_B/,/Section_A/ {print; c=3; next}
    c-- > 0
  ' \
| tac
```

```
Line 2
line 3
Line 4
Section_A
blah1
blah2
blah3
blah4
Section_B
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS based on one possible interpretation of your requirements:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^\n]+\n){2}Section_A.*Section_B' 'RT{print RT}' file
line 3
Line 4
Section_A
blah1
blah2
blah3
blah4
Section_B
```

Comment: easy but so efficient and all in a line!