# Deleting n lines in both directions and the match in sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Deleting the match and two lines before it works:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/match/,-2d' someCommonName.txt
```

Deleting the match and two lines after it works:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/match/,+2d' someCommonName.txt
```

But deleting the match, two lines after it and two lines before it does not work?

```
sed -i.bak -e '/match/-2,+2d' someCommonName.txt
sed: -e expression #1 unknown command: `-'
```

Why is that?

Comment: That `../somedir/*/someCommonName.txt` too dangerous?

Comment: the first one does not work to me: `seq 10 | sed -e '/5/,-2d'`, for example, returns the "sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unexpected `,'" error. In fact, I doubt the first command is working to you. See [Delete range of lines above pattern with sed (or awk)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29906/40596).

Comment: It is not dangerous, only that it is harder to read and go to the important point

Comment: You asked a question and 1 hour later selected an answer that does not contain a working solution. Just a thought - MAYBE if you'd left the question open longer you'd have got a working solution. FWIW the approach suggested in the accepted answer would not work for the edge case of 2 matching lines within 2 lines of each other.

Comment: It's probably too late by now as everyone will be looking at the recent posts. You could give it a day or so to see but you'll know for your next question. You should also post some concrete, testable, sample input and expected output that includes hard/non-obvious cases to handle, e.g. if you have `match` separated by just 1 line in your sample input file - what would the expected output be for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` operates on a range of addresses. That means either one or two expressions, not three.

`/match/` is an address which matches a regex.

`-2` is an address which specifies two lines before

`+2` is an address which specifies two lines after

Therefore:

`/match/,-2` is a range which specifies the line matching `match` to two lines before.

`/match/-2,+2d`, on the other hand, includes three addresses, and thus makes no sense.

To delete two lines before and after a pattern, I would recommend something like this ([modified from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20819408/2101267)):

```
sed -n "1N;2N;/\npattern$/{N;N;d};P;N;D"
```

This keeps 3 lines in the buffer and reads through the file. When the pattern is found in the last line, it reads two more lines and deletes all 5. Note that this will not work if the pattern is in the first two lines of the file, but it is  a start.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a complete solution but an outline: `sed` is a pretty simple tool which doesn't do two things at once. My approach would be to run `sed` once deleting the two lines after the pattern but keeping the pattern itself. The result can then be piped to `sed` again to remove the pattern and the two lines before.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i .bak '/match/,-2 {/match/!d;};/match/,+2d' YourFile
```

try this  (cannot test here, `-2` is not available in my sed version)

Comment: @nerronLeVelu Any idea what version you need?  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and it just came with it...but if I need to get a seperate package or recompile it or something, I'm game for that.

Comment: What is the !d? I get ` sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unexpected `,'` with gnu sed, Ubuntu 20_04

Comment: The minus does not work, [see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29906/delete-range-of-lines-above-pattern-with-sed-or-awk)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW this is how I'd really do the job (just change the `b` and `a` values to delete different numbers of lines before/after `match` is found):

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5 match
6
7
8
9

$ awk -v b=2 -v a=2 'NR==FNR{if (/match/) for (i=(NR-b);i<=(NR+a);i++) skip[i]; next } !(FNR in skip)' file file
1
2
8
9

$ awk -v b=3 -v a=1 'NR==FNR{if (/match/) for (i=(NR-b);i<=(NR+a);i++) skip[i]; next } !(FNR in skip)' file file
1
7
8
9
```

Note that the above assumes that when 2 "match"s appear within a removal window you want to base the deletions on the original occurrence, not what would happen after the first match being found causes the 2nd match to be deleted:

```
$ cat file2
1
2
3
4 match
5
6 match
7
8
9

$ awk -v b=2 -v a=2 'NR==FNR{if (/match/) for (i=(NR-b);i<=(NR+a);i++) skip[i]; next } !(FNR in skip)' file2 file2
1
9
```

as opposed to the output being:

```
1
7
8
9
```

since deleting the 2 lines after the first `match` would delete the 2nd `match` and so the 2 lines after THAT would not be deleted since they no longer are within 2 lines after a `match`.

Something else to consider:

```
$ diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' file <(grep -A2 -B2 match file)
1
2
8
9

$ diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' file2 <(grep -A2 -B2 match file2)
1
9
```

That uses bash and GNU diff 3.2, idk if/which other shells/diffs would support those constructs/options.