# Shell script for cleaning up listener.ora file

Tags: sed, unix-text-processing

we have listener.ora file as below

```
[oracle@orahow admin]$ more listener.ora
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host-ip-address)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = extproc))
    )
  )
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = extproc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /data/oracle/app/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = db11g.domain.com)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /data/oracle/app/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = db11g)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = db12c.domain.net)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /data/oracle/app/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = db12c)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = db12c.domain.net)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /data/oracle/app/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = db12c_DGMGRL)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = db18c.something)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /data/oracle/app/product/18.2.0.1/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = db18c_DGMGRL)
    )  )

INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER =0
```

i would like to remove specifically this particular block from the file.

```
(SID_DESC =
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME = db12c.domain.net)
  (ORACLE_HOME = /data/oracle/app/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1)
  (SID_NAME = db12c)
)
```

Need help on unix command/shell script to remove the exact block after oracle database decommission...

Comment: @Ahmet `bash` is not related to `sed` at all. `sed` is a binary on its own installed irrespective of the shell underlying

Comment: `this particular block` What is so particular about this block as compared to others? `Need help on unix command/shell script to remove` What help do you need? You can do the work in `sed`, but also in python or in pure bash, or in awk or in perl. You have to learn one of the tools, follow some tutorials, learn semantics and then approach this problem. If you want others to do the job for you, see a freelancing site. Ideally, you would write a full `(` `)` parser and tokenize input and extract this "particular" block using some matching. For that - interest in parsers and tokenization.

Comment: @Inian for such a small matter you don't hesitate giving information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### sed

This `sed` deletes the line with matching pattern `db12c)` along with previous 3 lines and following 1 line

```
 sed -n "1N;2N;3N;/db12c)/{N;d};P;N;D" listener.ora > listenerdel.ora
```

With the code above write it in a new file **or** modificate existing file with this:

```
sed -in "1N;2N;3N;/db12c)/{N;d};P;N;D" listener.ora
```

Please refer to this post.
[Deleting n lines in both directions and the match in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30487342/14320738)